# Pass component reference to component inside ngFor (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I pass component reference to another component if both components are in ngFor?

```
<div *ngFor="let address of fields?.addresses">
    <div>
        <o-lookup-dropdownlist></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
        <o-lookup-dropdownlist [cascade]="!!!linkToUpper o-lookup-dropdownlist !!!!"></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let address of fields?.addresses; let i = index">
    <div>
        <o-lookup-dropdownlist #first{{i}}></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
        <o-lookup-dropdownlist [cascade]="'first' + i"></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Use case:** (@methgaard)
I need component reference because second dropdownlist depends on result of the first one (country -> post code for example). If I have a component reference, I can disable second `o-lookup-dropdownlist` until first one has a value. (There is no point in selecting post code before you select country).

Comment: Have you tried just use `#first` and pass it like `[cascade]="first"`? If you haven't then i advice you to try it

Comment: what error does it throw when you try the above logic

Comment: why do you want the component reference?

Comment: @yurzui It works. Care to answer it, maybe with short answer why it works? I thought that anchorname should be unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanded version of `*ngFor="let address of fields?.addresses; let i = index"` will look like:

```html
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="fields?.addresses" let-address="$implicit" let-i="index">
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

For `ng-template` angular creates `EmbeddedView` that has its own scope.

So you can just use the same template reference variable inside `*ngFor`:

```html
<o-lookup-dropdownlist #first></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
<o-lookup-dropdownlist [cascade]="first"></o-lookup-dropdownlist>
```